# VBA Adding images to a MS Database as per its corrsponding data in the database entry

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is part of another question which has been resolved, pasting the link here for the convenient of those coming across in the future. 
Credit to Erik_von_Asmuth for his help previously.
[Using VBA to import a large number of attachment into Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659706/using-vba-to-import-a-large-number-of-attachment-into-microsoft-access/45661321?noredirect=1#comment78283227_45661321)

The concept of the code I think that might work:

```
Sub MacroInsertImageToDatabase()

Dim I As Integer 'number of row in file_paths.txt
Dim J As Integer 'number of entries in the database

For J = 1 To 100

For I = 1 To 100
'Lets say there are 100 lines in file_paths.txt. Something like:
'C:\image_folder/image1.jpg
'C:\image_folder/image2.jpg
'all the way to
'C:\image_folder/image100.jpg

    If (string of file_name in column 2 in the database) = (current row in file_paths.txt we are looking at)
    Then 'That means there is a match!
        [Attach the image from as given from file_paths.txt(we ar looking at) into the 3rd row of the database(we are looking at)]
        [also escape this loop through file_paths.txt so we can move onto the next entry in the database to repeat this If statement]
    Else 'current row in file_paths.txt we are looking at is NOT what we
        [move in the the next "I" iteration to look at the next row in file_paths.txt]

Next I 'successfull attached the image to the correponse entry in the database as per string in the 2nd column (file_name)


Next J 'now move on to the next row (entry) in the database, the "J" loop

End Sub
```

Or should I exploit the features of MS Access, I am reading the documentation about the "database table relationships". Have 1 table with just the attachments. Have another table with the corresponding file names (and other data). Then use the relationship features of MS Access to link them together.

Comment: Well, it's really never a good idea to store the same data twice in one table. I'd certainly go with relationships if I were you. There's a lot of information on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), the process of properly organizing your database with relations to minimize redundancy (store all data only once), and getting into it certainly pays off on the long run.

Comment: I agree with Erik. However, if these tables have 1-to-1 relationship, why not have just 1 table? Storing files in database can chew up Access 2GB size limit. Why even store in a table? Also, an attachment field is a multi-value field type and the filename should already be stored within the attachment field. So a text field with file name may be superfluous.

Comment: I agree that it is unnecessary to store data twice, which can increase the database size. But that is  my backup option while I am trying to create the code for attach files to the exact database entry (continuation from previous post, link referenced above).          I am proceeding under the assumption that I would not exceed the 2Gb file size.

Comment: store picture, its name, comment about picture etc. in one table ... if there are multiple comments for a picture, then store comments in another table, not with the picture ... the location, where the picture was taken, would go into another table because there could be multiple pictures at one location.  ... same with the camera that was used, put in separate table, because there could be multiple pictures per camera

Comment: Wasn't the entire file path stored in column 2? If so, there shouldn't be a reason to check file_paths.txt, you could just add the image stored in the location stored in column 2? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, so if my entire file paths is store in column 2, i can run a macro to call the file path in the 2nd column and attach the corresponding attachment into column 3?

Comment: yes, and way more easily than anything shown above. I'll show you in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to add attachments to your table based on the location set in the `file_name` column

```
Public Sub MacroInsertImageToDatabase()    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset, rsPictures As DAO.Recordset, ws As DAO.Workspace
    'Initialize database, workspace and recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set rsEmployees = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset)   

    Do While Not rsEmployees.EOF
        'Open the attachment recordset for the current record
        Set rsPictures = rsEmployees.Fields("attachment_column").Value
        'If there are no attachments yet
        If rsPictures.BOF Then
            'Edit the record
            rsEmployees.Edit
            'Begin a separate transaction for inserting the picture
            ws.BeginTrans
            'Load the picture
            rsPictures.AddNew
            rsPictures.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile rsEmployees.Fields("file_name")
            'Update the pictures recordset and commit the transaction to avoid troubles with nested transactions
            rsPictures.Update
            ws.CommitTrans
            rsPictures.Close
            'Then update the record (if anything has changed inside it, which it actually hasn't)
            rsEmployees.Update
        End If
        rsEmployees.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsEmployees.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: I am considering fool proof

Comment: fool-proofing this code a bit. In the case that the file_name column has a entry that specified a file_path that doesn't exist, the code would return an error "Run-time error 3024. Could not find file....". I overcame this by adding a new line of code "On Error Resume Next" after of the line "ws.BeginTrans", which now runs without an error. Interestingly, the attachment icon still indicated a file has been attached. When I clicked on this icon then click on the "added" attachment in the Attachment folder, a message "Unable to open xxx.jpg" appears, which made sense.

Comment: Although making the error message "go away" so the macro can carry on attaching files for the rest of the database. I am considering adding an IF statement so if a 3024 run-time error appears, a command is executed to stop the attachment process of a non-existent files, instead of just ignoring the error; then carry on with the DO WHILE loop.

Comment: I'd look at [this](http://allenbrowne.com/func-11.html) piece of code by Allen Browne to test if your file paths are valid. He has a lot of high-quality Access VBA on his site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this. Might take a while for a newb like me but is part of fun in the learning process. Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but for a "expansion/extension" to the answer already given to the original question, do I paste the code using the "Answer Your Question" button I see below the page?

Comment: I'd keep it to myself. Answers should be as minimal as possible, in my opinion. So specific refinements to escape errors are not really relevant